# How to find hidden UI elements in an iframe

Tags: selenium, iframe, automation, ui-automation, selenium-ide

I'm trying to record a Automation script using Selenium IDE. But when I'm clicking on elements inside the iframe it's not recording elements. Every clicks are recording only iframe div.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch to iframe manually. to do that

1. Add Select frame action and provide target (index=0 or any other
   locator)
2. Stop and start recording again.
3. Now you can record actions inside iframe.

You can see screenshot and at step#7 added **select frame** action, then restarted ide to capture actions.
Step# 9 is for switching out of iframe

[image: selenium ide screenshot]

Comment: sir this isn't working. it's only capturing the frame instead of elements

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure by the screen shot shared by you, but please ensure that you are not trying to capture the object of any added browser add-on for example - adobe flash player or any other such media player.

It wont work on it.
You can refer to https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html for flash automation

Comment: It isn't a browser add-on sir. It's a website with iframe (or might be adobe flash content not sure). I'm unable to capture elements from that iframe.

Comment: Probably the Iframe contains the adobe flash player content where you would not be abe to capture the content. to be sure, you can uninstall the flash player from your system and check whether you are able to see the content you are trying to capture? If you cannot see after uninstalling, you can be sure that it is flash player content.